# Output piped content to file and show number of lines in the file on stdout

Tags: shell-script, stdout, stderr

I would like to use `tee` to pipe content from `stdout` and `stderr` respectively into files (in fact append it with `> >(tee -a $filename)`). However, instead of seeing the contents appended to the file I would like to have some *real* progress indicator based on the piped content. Be it the number of lines in the output on the respective channel so far, or be it the number of characters or similar.

NB: Why did I emphasize *real* above? Because I am aware how to get a spinning baton through a subshell in the background and later kill it by keeping its PID stored. It's a nice moving thing, but doesn't really provide any indication about what's going on - i.e. it's snake oil.

btw: At the beginning the output file may not exist, so any solution with a subshell would have to consider this.

Comment: Just a thought, but rather than try and cobble something here why not just go to `inotify` and get the file events? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my-program > >(pv -trabcN stdout > stdout) 2> >(pv -trabcN stderr > stderr)
```

Would give you a progress like:

```
  stderr:  123MiB 0:00:03 [42.6MiB/s] [41.1MiB/s]
  stdout:  138MiB 0:00:03 [54.2MiB/s] [46.2MiB/s]
```

(current (`-r`) and average (`-a`) speed. `-a` is relatively recent, you can omit it if your version of `pv` doesn't have it).

Comment: Awesome solution, thanks! Good old `pv`. Not the first time I use it, but I had no idea it was this versatile :)

Comment: Apparently `-l` (aka `--line-mode`) is a nice option, too ... for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The -f (forever) option of the command tail might be useful.

Issuing a dot for every line of the file:

```
tail -f bk2ud.log | awk '{printf(".");}'
```

You might, however, be after something more elaborate depending on your needs..